# Having WCF service proxy configurable

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, wcf

I am writing a basic WPF GUI to connect to a WCF service and consume an interface. So far I have connected to the test system by creating a service reference, putting in the URI for the test service I want to consume, it finds the interface and creates the proxy via service reference for me.

What I want this to do when you run the GUI app is for the user to be able to pick an environment - development, test or production and for the GUI to then connect to the appropriate WCF service depending on the environment selected.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are the differences between your environments? Just the service URL? Does the GUI know the connection between the URL and the environment?

Comment: Just the service URL yes and it will only know the connection between URL and environment if I define it somewhere in configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `Endpoint` like this:

```
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(GetAddressForCurrentMode())
```

The other way you could to it, is to write a method, maybe an extension method, that accepts the service contract and the implementation class. Further more it either accepts a configuration name, or an endpoint:

```
public static TClient GetServiceClient<TClient, TContract>(string endpoint)
    where TClient : ClientBase<TContract>
{
   // Construct client
}
```

To construct the client, use one of `BaseClient<T>` overloads ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

To then consume the client, just use the method above as normal:

```
using(var client = ServiceInterop.
    GetServiceClient<MyClient, IMyContract>("http://foo.bar"))
{
    // Consume client
}
```